# Scala Null in json messaging problems

Tags: json, scala

So Im writing a very large integration library and for no particular reason, I decided to do it in Scala.  But, I encountered the `Int = null` issue and have yet to see a successful solution.  Heres the situation

```
class Dexter(val shouldILetLive: Boolean, val stabNumTimes: Int)
```

Now, instantiate it

```
me = new Dexter(true,null)
```

run thru jackson gets

```
me: {
  shouldILetLive: true
}
```

Or

```
me = new Dexter(false,10)
```

run thru jackson gets

```
me: {
  shouldILetLive: false,
  stabNumTimes: 10
}
```

awesome.  Here's the problem.  In my world, data means something.  AND lack of data means something.

```
me = new Dexter(null,null)

me: {
}
```

means I haven't answered the question yet.  So when dealing with a language that forces you to add values to those data elements, all of a sudden i get

```
me: {
  shouldILetLive: false,
  stabNumTimes: 0
}
```

Which means my company may have a director garroted.

Is there a solution I haven't come across yet?  Am I not seeing something or am I using the wrong language for messaging based systems.

thanks.

Comment: Given that Jackson is highly configurable, some sample code of how you're "running it through Jackson" would be useful.

Comment: thats buried about 5 libraries outside what im writing.  but its a basic object mapper.  but who cares, use  [insert json parser here]  and the problem is the identical.  `Dexter(false,0)` is in no way shape or form the same as `Dexter(null,null)`.  and [insert json parser here] will treat them very differently

Comment: `JsonInclude.Include.NON_DEFAULT` , have you tried using this?

Comment: If something is optional, then it should be kept in the `Option`, but I don't know if jackson supports it. Circe does https://github.com/circe/circe

Comment: yea, i know about that, but it doesn't solve the problem because the default still has to be either true or false.  still breaks the system.  or worse, you set the default to false.  now the ony time things show is if it is set to true.  even if the value is actually false

Comment: i saw circe.  It was very interesting and i may give it a spin.  But again, similar answer, in my pojo, how do i say "I havn't answered that yet".  Scala is the first language ive encountered where i can't do with null.  Its also going to cause problems in other Java programs that i have to interface with that expect null values for certain parameters.  Like, oh, death date.  if you havn't died yet, set the date value to null.  pretty basic stuff.

Comment: As I wrote;) Use `Option`, like this: `case class Dexter(houldILetLive: Option[Boolean], stabNumTimes: Option[Int])`. Then `val nobody = Dexter(None, None)` or `val me Dexter(Some(false), Some(1))`. If values is `None`, then circe will nod add the key at all to json. And look at "Semi-automatic derivation" https://circe.github.io/circe/codec.html to spare some work.

Comment: That's the Scala way: http://alvinalexander.com/scala/scala-null-values-option-uninitialized-variables

Comment: so `val nobody = Dexter(None, None)` then `nobody.shouldILetLive` would be null?

Answer (score 0):

Scala has a better way than Java to deal with missing data - the Maybe monad - which in implemented using [the Option type](http://danielwestheide.com/blog/2012/12/19/the-neophytes-guide-to-scala-part-5-the-option-type.html).
The example below serializes to Json and deserialize back ( is with Circe but you can probably do something similar with [Jackson scala module](https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-module-scala)) - you can see that all options are handled correctly

```
import io.circe.generic.auto._
import io.circe.parser._
import io.circe.syntax._
import io.circe.{DecodingFailure, Printer}

case class Dexter(shouldILetLive: Option[Boolean],stabNumTimes:Option[Int])

def serde(x: Dexter) ={
  val json=Printer.noSpaces.copy(dropNullKeys = true).pretty(x.asJson)
  println(json)
  decode[Dexter](json) match {
    case Left(x: DecodingFailure) => Dexter(None,None)
    case Right(d) => d
  }
}

serde(Dexter(None,None))
serde(Dexter(Some(true),None))
serde(Dexter(Some(false),Some(10)))
```

Comment: right, but once these pojo's are deserialied into objects, how does the `shouldILetLive: Option[Boolean] = None` appear to the millions of lines of java code i have?  Because if it is anything other than `null`, I have no choice than to go back to Groovy and do this with GroovyBeans

Comment: It's been awhile since I used Java but I'd think Option would not translate well. I guess you should add the need for Java interop in your question